# Set maximum value of integer field in template from context Django

Tags: python, django, templates, integer, field

I have a regular form with the basic template:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

The form consists of three integer fields defined in forms.py

```
class InitForm(forms.Form):
    row_1 = forms.IntegerField(initial=1, min_value=1)
    row_2 = forms.IntegerField(initial=1, min_value=1)
    row_3 = forms.IntegerField(initial=1, min_value=1)
```

The maximum value is set at runtime using input from the user. I have added it to the context by using

```
get_context_data()...
```

in the form view class, but how do I set the maximum input value for the three integer fields in the template? I can already output the maximum value in the template by

```
{{ maximum_value }}
```

I am just having trouble adding it to the form fields. For reference I need the maximum value on all the fields

Answer (score 1):

> Try the following in your template.

```
<input type="number" name="test" min="1" max="{{ maximum_value }}">
```

> Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_max.asp

Comment: can this be done by looping through all the form fields in the template?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to successfully implement this in django 2.2.7 by using the following:

In my class based FormView I set the maximum value, then update the form in the context:

```
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(InitView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        if self.csv_maximum_row:
            kwargs[self.csv_row_max_kwarg] = self.csv_maximum_row
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'].update_max()
        return context
```

as all the fields in the form require the maximum value the update max function in forms.py is:

```
    def update_max(self):
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({'max': self.csv_maximum_row})
```

when rendered the maximum value for the form in the template is the value set in the FormView class. This means you can still use basic templating:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

without having to dive into the HTML of the fields individually.